# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using awakeAfterUsingCoder with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access, automatic-ref-counting, nskeyedarchiver

I recently changed a bit of code using Archiver to replace the object being decoded with another if the object was in a shared list.  My app is using ARC.

```
- (id)awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder {
    Player* player = [[Team getCurrentTeam] getPlayerWithId: self.id];
    // If the player is in the current team then use that instance instead of this one.
    if (player !=  nil) {
        return player;
    } else {
        return self;
    }
}
```

The code worked great until I added the awakeAfterUsingCoder.  Now I am getting **malloc: error for object 0x7567430: pointer being freed was not allocated**.   It would appear that the object being replaced is being released but it was never retained? Since I'm using ARC I'm not sure what I might do to resolve this.

Comment: Does it work if you do `if (player != nil) { self = player; } return self;`?

Comment: Can you show what `getPlayerWithId:` does please?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I'm having something similar happen to me now.